# 'Error while creating add statement' no such table

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-5

I am using SQLite Database for storing some information like image name, date i am getting exception while i am trying to insert the data & it crashes the Application.

I have already cheked it by putting break points & Exception breakpoint it crashes because its not been able to find the table but table is already there.

see this : 
[image]

here is the crash report i am getting:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[PhotosPage savePhotosToDB], /Users/apple/Desktop/Mayur_iPhone/My Home Projects/Daily Photos Application/29thMar2013_DailyPhotos/iPhone/PhotosPage.m:168
2013-03-29 14:21:53.398 DailyPhotos[881:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error while creating add statement. 'no such table: PhotosTable''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b11012 0x1606e7e 0x1b10e78 0x5e5f35 0x9014 0x870d 0x161a705 0x92f920 0x92f8b8 0x9f0671 0x9f0bcf 0x9efd38 0x95f33f 0x95f552 0x93d3aa 0x92ecf8 0x26d7df9 0x26d7ad0 0x1a86bf5 0x1a86962 0x1ab7bb6 0x1ab6f44 0x1ab6e1b 0x26d67e3 0x26d6668 0x92c65c 0x7cad 0x1d45)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

Here is the Code i am using for Insert Data:

```
-(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    databaseName = @"DailyPhotosDB.rdb";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    if(success) return;
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DailyPhotosDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];
    [fileManager release];
}

-(void)savePhotosToDB
{
    [self checkAndCreateDatabase];
    sqlite3 *database;
    static sqlite3_stmt * addStmt ;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    databaseName = @"DailyPhotosDB.rdb";
    NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
    NSDateFormatter* df = [NSDateFormatter new];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    NSString *strCurDate = [df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

    if(!success)
    {
        NSString *defaultDBPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"DailyPhotosDB" ofType:@"sqlite"];
        success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
        if (!success)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        const char *sql = "insert into PhotosTable(PhotoName,CreationDate) Values(?,?)";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 1, [timeString UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [strCurDate UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        else
            sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
    }
    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: have you tried to run your query successfully in sqlite manager wizard?

Comment: @iAmbitious yea i already try that into sqlite manager it works fine.

Comment: Try adding a white space after your table name "insert into PhotosTable (PhotoName, CreationDate)...

Comment: have you deleted your app from device and tried it? Because I can see in your code that you have not replaced your db if it is already there in documents directory..

Comment: Debug your code using step debugging and see every object value proper or not and also print your query in console and check that query properly run on sqlite wizard

Comment: Good point by @CrimeMasterGOGO and this thing you forget to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced the same problem when i was implementing database & solved it by following way.

-> Go to Targets -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources click + on it & select Sqlite Database rdb file from resources.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Code

```
NSString *strquery=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into foodfinder(nameOfRestaurants,contacts,address,lats,longs) values(\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",nameOfRestaurants,contacts,address,lats,longs];
return [AppDelegate_iPhone executeQuery:strquery];
```

***Edit--> bellow code is from the comment***

```
NSString *strsrspath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"rdb"]; 
NSString *strdestpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/food.rdb",NSHomeDirectory()]; 
NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:strdestpath]) {
 NSLog(@"File Already Exist");
 } else { 
NSError *err; [manager copyItemAtPath:strsrspath toPath:strdestpath error:&err]; 
NSLog(@"file successfully copied"); 
return YES; 
} 
return NO;
```

Comment: You may add while creating.                                        NSString *strsrspath=[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"food" ofType:@"rdb"];
 
 NSString *strdestpath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/food.rdb",NSHomeDirectory()];
 
 NSFileManager *manager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
 
 if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:strdestpath]) {
  
  NSLog(@"File Already Exist");
 }
 else {
  NSError *err;
  [manager copyItemAtPath:strsrspath toPath:strdestpath error:&err];
  NSLog(@"file successfully copied");
  return YES;
 }
 return NO;

Answer (score 3):

actually you need to delete database what you created earlier and then add sqlite file to your bundle that will solve your issue .